# local effects and mutable state in Scala with Cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

In Functional Programming with Scala Chapter 14 (local effects and mutable state), the author state the following:

> We’ll call this new local-effects monad ST, which could stand for
> state thread, state transition, state token, or state tag. It’s
> different from the State monad in that its run method is protected,
> but otherwise its structure is exactly the same.

Overall it is a monad for scoped mutation.

I wonder if there is something that achieve this in cats-effects ? what is the DataType or TypeClass ?

Comment: What about Cat's state: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html ? Is this you looking for?

Comment: The author specifically state that it is not the state monad and we are talking of side effect